# all my components are placed over each other, i've been tryna figure it out a while now

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

can someone please tell me what i'm doing wrong, i tried laying ot panels first but same results, then i went back to using the components and same results, all the components a layed untop of each other, i've tried all sorts of things, same results, they're layed untop each other and to the middle

```
public class FnaComponents extends JPanel 
{

public FnaComponents()
{
    gridbag = new GridBagLayout();
    setLayout(gridbag);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,600));
    //setBackground(Color.lightGray);

    mainPanel = new JPanel(gridbag);
    mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));

    pTextField = new JTextField();
    //addcomponents(new JLabel("Policy #"), mainPanel, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, GridBagConstraints.NONE, GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST);
    //addcomponents(pTextField, mainPanel, null, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, GridBagConstraints.WEST);


    Invisible = new JButton();
    //addcomponents(Invisible, mainPanel, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, GridBagConstraints.NONE, GridBagConstraints.EAST);

    newbTextField = new JTextField();
    newbButton = new JButton("Cal Icon");
    //addcomponents(new JLabel("NB Date:"), mainPanel, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, GridBagConstraints.WEST);
    //addcomponents(newbTextField,mainPanel, null, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, GridBagConstraints.WEST);
    //addcomponents(newbButton,mainPanel, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, GridBagConstraints.WEST);

    bilimButton = new JComboBox<>(bilimits);
    bilimButton.setEditable(true);
    bicslButton = new JComboBox<>(bicsl);
    bicslButton.setEditable(true);
    //addcomponents(new JLabel("BI Limit:"), mainPanel, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, GridBagConstraints.WEST);
    //addcomponents(bilimButton, mainPanel, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, GridBagConstraints.WEST);
    //addcomponents(bicslButton,mainPanel, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, GridBagConstraints.WEST);


    lapseButton = new JComboBox<>(lapse);

    //addComponents(new JLabel("Lapse:"), tophalf, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, GridBagConstraints.WEST);
    //addComponents(lapseButton, lPanel);
    //addcomponents(lapseButton, tophalf, 3, 1, 0, 0, 4, 0, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, GridBagConstraints.WEST);


    addcomponents(mainPanel, this, null);
    add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

}
// method to add components to a container 
private void addcomponents(JComponent cont, Container main, Border border)
{
    Color code = new Color(0, 255, 255);

    Border padborder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10);
    Border bord = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(code, 1, true);
    border = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(bord, padborder);

    cont.setBorder(border);

    main.add(cont);  
}

// method to add components to a container 
private void addcomponents(JComponent cont, Container main, int gridx, int gridy, int gridwidth, int gridheight, double weightx, double weighty, int fill, int anchor)
{
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    gbc.gridx = gridx;
    gbc.gridy = gridy;
    gbc.gridwidth = gridwidth;
    gbc.gridheight = gridheight;
    gbc.weightx = weightx;
    gbc.weighty = weighty;
    gbc.fill = fill;
    gbc.anchor = anchor;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
    gridbag.setConstraints(cont, gbc);
    main.add(cont);
}

// method to add components to a container 
private void addcomponents(JComponent cont, Container main, Border border, int gridx, int gridy, int gridwidth, int gridheight, double weightx, double weighty, int fill, int anchor)
{
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    Color code = new Color(0, 255, 255);

    Border padborder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10);
    Border bord = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(code, 1, true); 
    border = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(bord, padborder);

    gbc.gridx = gridx;
    gbc.gridy = gridy;
    gbc.gridwidth = gridwidth;
    gbc.gridheight = gridheight;
    gbc.weightx = weightx;
    gbc.weighty = weighty;
    gbc.fill = fill;
    gbc.anchor = anchor;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);

    cont.setBorder(border);
    gridbag.setConstraints(cont, gbc);
    main.add(cont);  
}
}
```

Comment: please make sure that code you put down in question can be compiled and executed. Also try to condense your code showing exactly where you think problem could be

Comment: see thats the thing i'm not sure but i strongly believe its in the methods i created

Comment: Non of the code  you've provided actually adds any components to your container, in fact, you code generates a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`

Comment: it runs for me, i think i left out a few things, i just pasted the code that i thought was suspicious of the errors

Comment: See also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is a little hard to read...

First, I'd advise against sharing the same instance of `GridBagLayout` between containers...

```
gridbag = new GridBagLayout();
setLayout(gridbag);
//...
mainPanel = new JPanel(gridbag);
```

This could cause issues, instead, give each container their own instance of `GridBagLayout`

This means you won't be able to do something like `gridbag.setConstraints(cont, gbc);` and in fact, I'd probably recommend against it based on the way you code is trying to work, instead, use something like `main.add(cont, gbc)`, which will pass the constraints down to the currently assigned layout manager.

Second, `gridwidth` and `gridheight` should be no less then `1` in normal cases, otherwise, you end up with the issues you have

So you should be using something more like...

```
addcomponents(new JLabel("Policy #"), mainPanel, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, GridBagConstraints.NONE, GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST);
addcomponents(pTextField, mainPanel, null, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, GridBagConstraints.WEST);
```

While this is okay, because of the number of parameters, it becomes really easy to lose track of which parameter does what.  I might consider using a builder pattern instead to build the constraints, but that's me